# Modificar claves del array por otros valores

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente array que deseo modificar la clave por otro valor que tengo en otro array:

```
$respuesta = array( 
 0=> array:16 ( 
   0=> null 
   1=> "1313" 
   2=> "01/01/2015" 
   3=> "01/01/2015" 
   4=> "27/04/1983" 
   5=> "01" 
   6=> "41821550" 
   7=> "ACOSTA LOPEZ LUIS GIANCARLO" 
   8=> "604311LALSE0" 
   9=> null 
   10=> null 
   11=> "0" 
   12=> "03" 
   13=> "AFP PROFUTURO" 
   14=> null 
   15=> null 
   16=> "4342.50" 
)
1=> array( 
  0=> null 1=> "" 
   2=> "04/05/2015" 
   3=> "04/05/2015" 
   4=> "01/01/01" 
   5=> "01" 
   6=> "41414242" 
   7=> "AGUIRRE VALDERRAMA DANIEL" 
   8=> "" 
   9=> null 
   10=> null 
   11=> "1" 
   12=> "08" 
   13=> "O.N.P." 
   14=> null 
   15=> null 
   16=> null 
)
)
```

Y en este otro array tengo los valores que quiero colorar en las claves de mi array:

```
$claves= array(
  0 => "l_ubig"
  1 => "n_cusp"
  2 => "f_ingr"
  3 => "f_inic"
  4 => "f_naci"
  5 => "c_docu"
  6 => "n_docu"
  7 => "xl_nomc"
  8 => "c_autg"
  9 => "k_cont"
  10 => "l_cont"
  11 => "Situacion"
  12 => "c_afp"
  13 => "l_afp"
  14 => "xp_totafp"
  15 => "01001"
  16 => "01002"
)
```

Y el resultado que deseo obtener es el siguiente:

```
$respuesta = array( 
 0=> array:16 ( 
   l_ubig=> null 
   n_cusp=> "1313" 
   f_ingr=> "01/01/2015" 
   f_inic=> "01/01/2015" 
   f_naci=> "27/04/1983" 
   c_docu=> "01" 
   n_docu=> "41821550" 
   xl_nomc=> "ACOSTA LOPEZ LUIS GIANCARLO" 
   c_autg=> "604311LALSE0" 
   k_cont=> null 
   l_cont=> null 
   Situacion=> "0" 
   c_afp=> "03" 
   l_afp=> "AFP PROFUTURO" 
   xp_totafp=> null 
   01001=> null 
   01002=> "4342.50" 
)
1=> array( 
   l_ubig=> null 
   n_cusp=> "" 
   f_ingr=> "04/05/2015" 
   f_inic=> "04/05/2015" 
   f_naci=> "01/01/01" 
   c_docu=> "01" 
   n_docu=> "41414242" 
   xl_nomc=> "AGUIRRE VALDERRAMA DANIEL" 
   c_autg=> "" 
   k_cont=> null 
   l_cont=> null 
   Situacion=> "1" 
   c_afp=> "08" 
   l_afp=> "O.N.P." 
   xp_totafp=> null 
   01001=> null 
   01002=> null 
)
)
```

He estado tratando de hacerlo con la función `array_combine()`, que crea un nuevo array, usando una matriz para las claves y otra para sus valores.

Lo he estado realizando de la siguiente manera, no sé si es la correcta:

```
$result = array_combine($claves, $respuesta);
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> Error_Exception: array_combine{}: Both parameters should have an equal number of elements.

Espero me puedan ayudar a como obtener el resultado que quiero y de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Justo lo que pone, debes hacer eso por cada elemento de `$respuesta`, no por la matriz misma que sólo tiene 2 elementos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes hacer la combinación de arrays dentro de cada uno de los elementos del array respuesta, y combinar con los valores.
Lo muestro en el siguiente ejemplo con un `var_dump` del array resultante.

```
$respuesta = array( 
 0=> array ( 
   0=> null ,
   1=> "1313" ,
   2=> "01/01/2015" ,
   3=> "01/01/2015" ,
   4=> "27/04/1983" ,
   5=> "01" ,
   6=> "41821550" ,
   7=> "ACOSTA LOPEZ LUIS GIANCARLO" ,
   8=> "604311LALSE0" ,
   9=> null ,
   10=> null ,
   11=> "0" ,
   12=> "03" ,
   13=> "AFP PROFUTURO" ,
   14=> null ,
   15=> null ,
   16=> "4342.50" 
),
1=> array( 
  0=> null, 1=> "", 
   2=> "04/05/2015" ,
   3=> "04/05/2015" ,
   4=> "01/01/01" ,
   5=> "01" ,
   6=> "41414242" ,
   7=> "AGUIRRE VALDERRAMA DANIEL" ,
   8=> "" ,
   9=> null ,
   10=> null ,
   11=> "1" ,
   12=> "08" ,
   13=> "O.N.P." ,
   14=> null ,
   15=> null ,
   16=> null 
)
);
$claves= array(
  "l_ubig",
  "n_cusp",
  "f_ingr",
  "f_inic",
   "f_naci",
   "c_docu",
  "n_docu",
  "xl_nomc",
   "c_autg",
   "k_cont",
   "l_cont",
   "Situacion",
  "c_afp",
  "l_afp",
  "xp_totafp",
  "01001",
  "01002",
);

$anewlist = array();
foreach ($respuesta as $res) {
    $anewlist[] = array_combine($claves, array_values($res));
}

var_dump($anewlist);

array(2) { [0]=> array(17) { ["l_ubig"]=> NULL ["n_cusp"]=> string(4) "1313" ["f_ingr"]=> string(10) "01/01/2015" ["f_inic"]=> string(10) "01/01/2015" ["f_naci"]=> string(10) "27/04/1983" ["c_docu"]=> string(2) "01" ["n_docu"]=> string(8) "41821550" ["xl_nomc"]=> string(27) "ACOSTA LOPEZ LUIS GIANCARLO" ["c_autg"]=> string(12) "604311LALSE0" ["k_cont"]=> NULL ["l_cont"]=> NULL ["Situacion"]=> string(1) "0" ["c_afp"]=> string(2) "03" ["l_afp"]=> string(13) "AFP PROFUTURO" ["xp_totafp"]=> NULL ["01001"]=> NULL ["01002"]=> string(7) "4342.50" } [1]=> array(17) { ["l_ubig"]=> NULL ["n_cusp"]=> string(0) "" ["f_ingr"]=> string(10) "04/05/2015" ["f_inic"]=> string(10) "04/05/2015" ["f_naci"]=> string(8) "01/01/01" ["c_docu"]=> string(2) "01" ["n_docu"]=> string(8) "41414242" ["xl_nomc"]=> string(25) "AGUIRRE VALDERRAMA DANIEL" ["c_autg"]=> string(0) "" ["k_cont"]=> NULL ["l_cont"]=> NULL ["Situacion"]=> string(1) "1" ["c_afp"]=> string(2) "08" ["l_afp"]=> string(6) "O.N.P." ["xp_totafp"]=> NULL ["01001"]=> NULL ["01002"]=> NULL } }
```

Comment: Muy parecido a este código era el que iba a publicar :D mi +1. PD: Al final lo publiqué ;)

Answer (score 0):

### Explicación del problema

Estás tratando de aplicar `array_combine` a `$respuesta`, que es una matriz con dos elementos que, a su vez, son la matriz a la que realmente quieres aplicar ese cambio.

### Solución propuesta

Debes iterar por cada elemento de `$respuesta` y a cada elemento es al que deseas realizar el cambio de índices.

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach($respuesta as $indice => $datos) {
  $respuesta[$indice] = array_combine($claves, $datos);
}
```

### Ejemplo completo

Un ejemplo completo:

```
<?php
$respuesta = array(
 0=> array(
   0=> null,
   1=> "1313",
   2=> "01/01/2015",
   3=> "01/01/2015",
   4=> "27/04/1983",
   5=> "01",
   6=> "41821550",
   7=> "ACOSTA LOPEZ LUIS GIANCARLO",
   8=> "604311LALSE0",
   9=> null,
   10=> null,
   11=> "0",
   12=> "03",
   13=> "AFP PROFUTURO",
   14=> null,
   15=> null,
   16=> "4342.50",
  ),
  1=> array(
   0=> null,
   1=> "",
   2=> "04/05/2015",
   3=> "04/05/2015",
   4=> "01/01/01",
   5=> "01",
   6=> "41414242",
   7=> "AGUIRRE VALDERRAMA DANIEL",
   8=> "",
   9=> null,
   10=> null,
   11=> "1",
   12=> "08",
   13=> "O.N.P.",
   14=> null,
   15=> null,
   16=> null,
  ),
);
$claves= array(
  0 => "l_ubig",
  1 => "n_cusp",
  2 => "f_ingr",
  3 => "f_inic",
  4 => "f_naci",
  5 => "c_docu",
  6 => "n_docu",
  7 => "xl_nomc",
  8 => "c_autg",
  9 => "k_cont",
  10 => "l_cont",
  11 => "Situacion",
  12 => "c_afp",
  13 => "l_afp",
  14 => "xp_totafp",
  15 => "01001",
  16 => "01002",
);
foreach($respuesta as $indice => $datos) {
  $respuesta[$indice] = array_combine($claves, $datos);
}
echo json_encode($respuesta, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Y la salida:

```
[
    {
        "l_ubig": null,
        "n_cusp": "1313",
        "f_ingr": "01\/01\/2015",
        "f_inic": "01\/01\/2015",
        "f_naci": "27\/04\/1983",
        "c_docu": "01",
        "n_docu": "41821550",
        "xl_nomc": "ACOSTA LOPEZ LUIS GIANCARLO",
        "c_autg": "604311LALSE0",
        "k_cont": null,
        "l_cont": null,
        "Situacion": "0",
        "c_afp": "03",
        "l_afp": "AFP PROFUTURO",
        "xp_totafp": null,
        "01001": null,
        "01002": "4342.50"
    },
    {
        "l_ubig": null,
        "n_cusp": "",
        "f_ingr": "04\/05\/2015",
        "f_inic": "04\/05\/2015",
        "f_naci": "01\/01\/01",
        "c_docu": "01",
        "n_docu": "41414242",
        "xl_nomc": "AGUIRRE VALDERRAMA DANIEL",
        "c_autg": "",
        "k_cont": null,
        "l_cont": null,
        "Situacion": "1",
        "c_afp": "08",
        "l_afp": "O.N.P.",
        "xp_totafp": null,
        "01001": null,
        "01002": null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_combine` tiene restricciones que podrían ser muy problemáticas.

1. Si `$claves` tuviera más o menos elementos que cualquiera de los sub-arrays el código no arrojará los resultados esperados
2. Igualmente, si cualquiera de los sub-arrays tuviera un tamaño distinto de `$claves` el código fallará.

En esos casos una solución como esta podría ser factible porque aquí se crean en `$new_array` solamente aquellas claves que sean encontradas en `$claves`.

### Prueba cuando son iguales todos:

```
$respuesta = array(
 0=> array(
   0=> null,
   1=> "1313",
   2=> "01/01/2015",
   3=> "01/01/2015",
   4=> "27/04/1983",
   5=> "01",
   6=> "41821550",
   7=> "ACOSTA LOPEZ LUIS GIANCARLO",
   8=> "604311LALSE0",
   9=> null,
   10=> null,
   11=> "0",
   12=> "03",
   13=> "AFP PROFUTURO",
   14=> null,
   15=> null,
   16=> "4342.50",
  ),
  1=> array(
   0=> null,
   1=> "",
   2=> "04/05/2015",
   3=> "04/05/2015",
   4=> "01/01/01",
   5=> "01",
   6=> "41414242",
   7=> "AGUIRRE VALDERRAMA DANIEL",
   8=> "",
   9=> null,
   10=> null,
   11=> "1",
   12=> "08",
   13=> "O.N.P.",
   14=> null,
   15=> null,
   16=> null,
  ),
);

$claves= array(
  "l_ubig",
  "n_cusp",
  "f_ingr",
  "f_inic",
  "f_naci",
  "c_docu",
  "n_docu",
  "xl_nomc",
  "c_autg",
  "k_cont",
  "l_cont",
  "Situacion",
  "c_afp",
  "l_afp",
  "xp_totafp",
  "01001",
  "01002",
);

$mNew=array();
foreach($respuesta as $indice => $datos) {    
    foreach ($datos as $k=>$v) {
            $mNew[$indice][$claves[$k]] =  $v;
    }
}

var_dump($mNew);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(17) {
    ["l_ubig"]=>
    NULL
    ["n_cusp"]=>
    string(4) "1313"
    ["f_ingr"]=>
    string(10) "01/01/2015"
    ["f_inic"]=>
    string(10) "01/01/2015"
    ["f_naci"]=>
    string(10) "27/04/1983"
    ["c_docu"]=>
    string(2) "01"
    ["n_docu"]=>
    string(8) "41821550"
    ["xl_nomc"]=>
    string(27) "ACOSTA LOPEZ LUIS GIANCARLO"
    ["c_autg"]=>
    string(12) "604311LALSE0"
    ["k_cont"]=>
    NULL
    ["l_cont"]=>
    NULL
    ["Situacion"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["c_afp"]=>
    string(2) "03"
    ["l_afp"]=>
    string(13) "AFP PROFUTURO"
    ["xp_totafp"]=>
    NULL
    ["01001"]=>
    NULL
    ["01002"]=>
    string(7) "4342.50"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(17) {
    ["l_ubig"]=>
    NULL
    ["n_cusp"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["f_ingr"]=>
    string(10) "04/05/2015"
    ["f_inic"]=>
    string(10) "04/05/2015"
    ["f_naci"]=>
    string(8) "01/01/01"
    ["c_docu"]=>
    string(2) "01"
    ["n_docu"]=>
    string(8) "41414242"
    ["xl_nomc"]=>
    string(25) "AGUIRRE VALDERRAMA DANIEL"
    ["c_autg"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["k_cont"]=>
    NULL
    ["l_cont"]=>
    NULL
    ["Situacion"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["c_afp"]=>
    string(2) "08"
    ["l_afp"]=>
    string(6) "O.N.P."
    ["xp_totafp"]=>
    NULL
    ["01001"]=>
    NULL
    ["01002"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

### Prueba teniendo `$claves` más elementos

```
$respuesta = array(
 0=> array(
   0=> null,
   1=> "1313",
   2=> "01/01/2015",
   3=> "01/01/2015",
   4=> "27/04/1983",
   5=> "01",
   6=> "41821550",
   7=> "ACOSTA LOPEZ LUIS GIANCARLO",
   8=> "604311LALSE0",
   9=> null,
   10=> null,
   11=> "0",
   12=> "03",
   13=> "AFP PROFUTURO",
   14=> null,
   15=> null,
   16=> "4342.50",
  ),
  1=> array(
   0=> null,
   1=> "",
   2=> "04/05/2015",
   3=> "04/05/2015",
   4=> "01/01/01",
   5=> "01",
   6=> "41414242",
   7=> "AGUIRRE VALDERRAMA DANIEL",
   8=> "",
   9=> null,
   10=> null,
   11=> "1",
   12=> "08",
   13=> "O.N.P.",
   14=> null,
   15=> null,
   16=> null,
  ),
);

$claves= array(
  "l_ubig",
  "n_cusp",
  "f_ingr",
  "f_inic",
  "f_naci",
  "c_docu",
  "n_docu",
  "xl_nomc",
  "c_autg",
  "k_cont",
  "l_cont",
  "Situacion",
  "c_afp",
  "l_afp",
  "xp_totafp",
  "01001",
  "01002",
  "9999"
);

$mNew=array();
foreach($respuesta as $indice => $datos) {    
    foreach ($datos as $k=>$v) {
            $mNew[$indice][$claves[$k]] =  $v;
    }
}

var_dump($mNew);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(17) {
    ["l_ubig"]=>
    NULL
    ["n_cusp"]=>
    string(4) "1313"
    ["f_ingr"]=>
    string(10) "01/01/2015"
    ["f_inic"]=>
    string(10) "01/01/2015"
    ["f_naci"]=>
    string(10) "27/04/1983"
    ["c_docu"]=>
    string(2) "01"
    ["n_docu"]=>
    string(8) "41821550"
    ["xl_nomc"]=>
    string(27) "ACOSTA LOPEZ LUIS GIANCARLO"
    ["c_autg"]=>
    string(12) "604311LALSE0"
    ["k_cont"]=>
    NULL
    ["l_cont"]=>
    NULL
    ["Situacion"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["c_afp"]=>
    string(2) "03"
    ["l_afp"]=>
    string(13) "AFP PROFUTURO"
    ["xp_totafp"]=>
    NULL
    ["01001"]=>
    NULL
    ["01002"]=>
    string(7) "4342.50"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(17) {
    ["l_ubig"]=>
    NULL
    ["n_cusp"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["f_ingr"]=>
    string(10) "04/05/2015"
    ["f_inic"]=>
    string(10) "04/05/2015"
    ["f_naci"]=>
    string(8) "01/01/01"
    ["c_docu"]=>
    string(2) "01"
    ["n_docu"]=>
    string(8) "41414242"
    ["xl_nomc"]=>
    string(25) "AGUIRRE VALDERRAMA DANIEL"
    ["c_autg"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["k_cont"]=>
    NULL
    ["l_cont"]=>
    NULL
    ["Situacion"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["c_afp"]=>
    string(2) "08"
    ["l_afp"]=>
    string(6) "O.N.P."
    ["xp_totafp"]=>
    NULL
    ["01001"]=>
    NULL
    ["01002"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Así mismo puedes probar quitando elementos de `$respuesta`. En ningún caso el código funcionará de manera inesperada.